# Type casting and inspection query

Tags: swift, types, casting

I am currently working through the basics of Type Casting and Inspection in swift 4.  I have found an example in the Apple Developer book which i need a bit of help with.

They have an exercise to create an Any type dictionary and then unwrap the values looping through the dictionary. The given solution shows the for loop with the value in brackets and each value being unwrapped. Can someone give an explanation for the solution shown? and is there another(simple) way to solve this? There is not enough information in the book.

```
let anythingAndEverything: [String: Any] = ["FirstBool": true, 
"FalseBool": false, "Unknown": "90", "AnInteger": 12, "ADouble": 1.1]

print(anythingAndEverything)

var total: Double = 0
for (_, value) in anythingAndEverything {
    if let value = value as? Bool {
        if value {
            total += 2
        } else {
            total -= 3
        }
    } else if let value = value as? Double {
        total += value
    } else if let value = value as? Int {
        total += Double(value)
    } else if let value = value as? String {
        total += 1
    }
}

print(total)
```

Many thanks for any help in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dictionary` conforms to `Collection`, which conforms to `Sequence`. This means that a dictionary can be looped through using a for...in loop.

In the definition of `Dictionary`, there is this line:

```
public typealias Element = (key: Key, value: Value)
```

This means that "in the collection called a dictionary, it contains elements of type `(key: Key, value: Value)`". This means that you will get `(key: Key, value: Value)` as the type of the variable before `in`:

```
for element in someDictionary {
    // element is of type (key: Key, value: Value)
}
```

Since `element` is a tuple, we can actually unwrap the tuple by doing this:

```
for (key, value) in someDictionary {}
```

In your specific situation, we don't need the `key` bit, so we write `_` to say "throw this away":

```
for (_, value) in someDictionary {}
```

Another way to solve this is to use `reduce`. I wouldn't say this is necessarily simpler though:

```
total = anythingAndEverything.reduce(0.0) { (x, y) -> Double in
    if let value = y.value as? Bool {
        if value {
            return x + 2
        } else {
            return x - 3
        }
    } else if let value = y.value as? Double {
        return x + value
    } else if let value = y.value as? Int {
        return x + Double(value)
    } else if let value = y.value as? String {
        return x + 1
    } else {
        return x
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Sweeper that has certainly clarified some of my confusion. I will have an experiment with the reduce solution you suggest above and see if i can get an example to work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, I recommend you to read an official explanation from [Apple's Swift guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html). There is also a great example looping through Collection and using `switch statement` to check for value's type.

```
for thing in things {
    switch thing {
    case 0 as Int:
        print("zero as an Int")
    case 0 as Double:
        print("zero as a Double")
    case let someInt as Int:
        print("an integer value of \(someInt)")
    case let someDouble as Double where someDouble > 0:
        print("a positive double value of \(someDouble)")
    case is Double:
        print("some other double value that I don't want to print")
    case let someString as String:
        print("a string value of \"\(someString)\"")
    case let (x, y) as (Double, Double):
        print("an (x, y) point at \(x), \(y)")
    case let movie as Movie:
        print("a movie called \(movie.name), dir. \(movie.director)")
    case let stringConverter as (String) -> String:
        print(stringConverter("Michael"))
    default:
        print("something else")
    }
}
```

I would also like to explain this part:

```
case let varName as TypeName
```

This means that if the new `varName` equal the non-optional version of `thing` and also of type `TypeName`, do the next with it.

Comment: thank you Stepan :-) i had read through the example in the Apple Swift guide but was still struggling. I will try some practice exercises with case let. The example you have put above seems very straightforward.